# Save data in MariaDB with non-existent references

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

implementing a web that consists of votes from images from external sources I found a problem.

Tables in MariaDb:

User

- id
- name

Photo

- id
- url
- platform

Vote

- userId
- photoId

The problem is that my platform does not have the external photos, I just keep the references to them. Whenever the user votes a photo I have to check if that photo(Url) is in the "Photo" table. The "Photo" table is designed so  you do not have to duplicate information in each vote. Is there any better way to have a reference to the Photo voted without having to "index" all the photos? I worry about performance.

Comment: Your design is a standard normalized solution to the problem.  You state that url is a problem.  In what way?  The url is probably a varchar of some sort.  While url's can be large, and the table could grow to great length, standard mysql indexing will insure that searching for a Photo row by url will be very efficient.

Comment: maybe you could make the id part of the photo url? are they all on the same domain, organized to a strict naming/numbering pattern?

Comment: They are not in the same domain, they are multi-platform. I really do not use the URL to identify a photo, I use the concrete ID of the photo on the platform to be able to make calls to each API.I just wanted to simplify the example. Being the ID each platform uses its identification system, so I need the platform and ID.The "Photo" table serves as an abstraction of my internal system to external photos. I hope that with a good Amazon server MariaDB works well in my case. Thank you very much for answering.